# How can I remove a control (e.g. group box) in WPF programmatically?

Tags: wpf, controls, wrappanel

I am using a WrapPanel and because I want to save space I want to remove (not hide) some controls (some of them are group boxes) depending on some features.

What command should I use to remove a control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Remove()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590022%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method or its variant, such as [`RemoveRange()` & `RemoveAt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), to remove control(s) from a panel :

```
myWrapPanel.Children.Remove(myGroupBox);
```

Or simply set [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to `Collapsed` on controls that you want to hide :

```
myGroupBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collpased;
```

That won't cause empty space reserved for those hidden controls as described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) :

> `Visibility.Collapsed`: Do not display the element, and do not reserve space for it in layout.

Comment: The Collapsed method is indeed the best way and exactly what I need.